# Bug in unorthodox merge sort implementation

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, user-controls, mergesort

I've been working on a very specific merge sort implementation; one where the user manually compares elements during the steps of the sorting algorithm. To achieve this, I tried to adapt this [code](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/merge-sort-in-python) so the program asks for a user input on comparison.

I tested it on a list of length 4, but came across some strange behaviour. For example, inputting `[2, 3, 1, 4]` yields `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as it should, but `[2, 4, 1, 3]` returns `[1, 2, 4, 3]`. I've tried to analyse what exactly happens step by step by printing `array`, `q`, `p` and `r` during the process, but I can't figure out what might be the issue. Looking online didn't help me very much either, considering my implementation is unique as far as I know. Thank you sincerely in advance for any help.

```
def mergie(array):
    size = len(array)
    if size > 1:
        middle = size // 2
        subl = array[:middle]
        subr = array[middle:]
 
        mergie(subl)
        mergie(subr)
        
        p = 0
        q = 0
        r = 0
 
        leftl = len(subl)
        rightl = len(subr)
        while p < leftl and q < rightl:
            if subl[p]:
                print("Top : ", subl[p]) 
                
            else:
                print("Top : NULL")
                
            if subr[q]:
                print("Bottom :", subr[q])
            
            else:
                print("Bottom : NULL")
                
            inp = ""
            while inp != "p" and inp != "b":
                inp = input("Do you prefer top (p) or bottom (b) ? ")
                if inp != "p" and inp != "b":
                    print("Please use p or b")
                    
                if inp == "b":                  
                    print("Bottom chosen.\n")
                    array[r] = subl[p]
                    p += 1                 
                
                if inp == "p": 
                    print("Top chosen.\n")
                    array[r] = subr[q]
                    q += 1               
                    
                if inp == "p" or inp == "b":
                    r += 1            
                
            while p < leftl:
                array[r] = subl[p]
                p += 1
                r += 1
                
            while q < rightl:
                array[r] = subr[q]
                q += 1
                r += 1







testie4 = [2, 4, 1, 3]

print("--------------------------------------------\nInput array: \n")
print(testie4, "\n--------------------------------------------\n")

mergie(testie4)
print("--------------------------------------------\nSorted array: \n")
print(testie4, "\n--------------------------------------------\n")
```